# Aligning currency values in table

Tags: html, css

I have a currency values for example:

```
4.50€, 25.30€, 446,60€
```

I set the `td` `text-align` property to `right`

```
  4.50€
 25.30€
446.60€
```

The only problem now is that all my content now starts from the right side of the `td`.

What i would like to achieve is **right text formatting** starting **from the left side**.

Something like that:

```
id     |money     |
-------------------
0      |  4.50€   |
1      | 25.30€   |
2      |446.60€   |
```

Comment: Not a duplicate. This is not about alignment really but about getting some spacing. (The question mentions how the desired alignment has been achieved.)

Comment: How is the width of the column set? This greatly affects the suitability of different approaches.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela width is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If your contents are static then you can try the following:-

```
 <style>
        td, th{
            border: 1px solid #777;
        }
        td{
            width: 100px;
        }
        td div{
            width: 42%;
            text-align: right;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                SL No.
            </th>
            <th>
                Price
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                1
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>4.2</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                2
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>4.22</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                1
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>4.222</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

But I know, if the content is dynamic it'll not solve the problem completely.